# Color coding in Android Studio when adding class

Tags: android, class

I have been adding a new class in Android Studio, but the pre-made classes were already in blue. The one that I created is in red. Then I created another one and linked it into Git and it turned green. How can I make the red color file into a blue colored one?

**Here is the screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: Red files indicating the conflicts or errors in it, where Green represents the new file to be added. First resolve the errors and execute the commands to add and commit.

Comment: When having an error, the file will have a red underline on it's name but the font color is still blue. In the screenshot, Bot.java is colored in font red and contains no error.

Comment: Have add this file and commit. Also try to clean and re-build the project. Try to pull origin.

Comment: why the vote down?

Comment: Don't know, i am not the one. You can check in the details.

Comment: @jitainsharma Actually, a red file means it hasn't been added to staging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These colours correlate to your Version Control System.

Red indicates a file hasn't been added to staging - this means that when you run `git commit`, the red files will not be included. Calling `git add` on the file will add to staging and turn it green.

Green indicates a completely new file is in staging, and will be committed to the git repository when you run `git commit`

Blue indicates a file that is in staging, but that has been modified.

So, green or blue doesn't matter - both file are in staging. It simply indicates whether a file has been newly added, or has been modified.

Also see [this post, "What does stage mean in git?"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/119782/what-does-stage-mean-in-git)

**Edit**:
You can also run `git status` from the terminal in Android Studio to see how the file colours match.